# Moving columns based on a row value from one data frame into an empty data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have made a 2 by n dataframe from a text file using

`with open('test.txt') as a:
    Thresholds = pd.read_table(a, sep=',')`

where the first row is a row of headers that could be different every time a new file is to be brought in, and the data consists of a row of 1s and 0s.

```
  A B C D E F G
  1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

I am trying to then either delete all the columns with 0s or move all of the columns with 1s into an empty dataframe. I am used to writing in R or matlab and have done this in both of these languages, however I'm not too sure how to go about writing this in Python.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use boolean indexing on then df.columns the drop those columns from the dataframe:

```
df.drop(df.columns[~df.iloc[0].astype(bool)],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  D  E  G
0  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0,2,1),
         'B': np.random.randint(0,2,1),
         'C': np.random.randint(0,2,1),
         'D': np.random.randint(0,2,1),
         'E': np.random.randint(0,2,1),
         'F': np.random.randint(0,2,1),
         'G': np.random.randint(0,2,1)})

mask = df.ix[0] == 1
df = df[df.columns[mask]]
```

This returns:

```
   C  D  F
0  1  1  1
```

Comment: df.ix is deprecated in pandas 0.20.1... 
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: DeprecationWarning: 
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing